Browser cache disabling doesn't work with PDF
I work on a HTML page (lets call it page1.php) which includes a link to a PDF file (either to download it or see it in client's browser). But this PDF may change sometimes and I would like to keep the same name / folder for the new version (the new one replaces the ancient every time). You may already know what my problem is : when I upload the new version of my PDF file, users see the ancient.
Here are the results of some tests :

When I empty my browser cache, and I click on the link again, I get the new version of the PDF. So it is a caching problem.
I tried what you can find about cache disabling on page1.php (see below). I checked the response header of page1.php in the developper's toolkit, and the headers are correct. But I still get then ancient version of the PDF after uploading a new one. Note that the cache folder of my file system keeps reciving new files after I flushing it and reloading page1.php which he shouldn't in my opinion.

<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">

or
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

Btw : my browser is Chrome 128.0.6613.113 and it load the PDF file directly in tabs
So i'm a little stucked here. Do you guys have any ideas ?
Thanks a lot

You could add a current timestamp parameter to the URL of the PDF, like this: https://example.com/directory/myPdf?t=27346347374. Since the added timestamp will change the URL, the pdf file shouldn't be cached by a browser. You also need to make sure that the web page serving the URL isn't cached.

"I tried what you can find about cache disabling on page1.php" Setting cache headers on the HTML page has no effect on the PDF.

Usually, any common browser could be able to handle this without getting PHP involved. Which headers are set when the PDF is downloaded the first time? Does this involve a large caching time?

If you're using Apache, as the webserver, you can also use that to set the time to cache for PDF files. See: mod_expires.

@Olivier I also thought so. But since i haven't found anythig more revelant, I tried that...

@NicoHaase Is this the answer you expect ? cache-control:max-age=2592000, public I dont know how to change this for the PDF

@KIKOSoftware for what I understood,, the "mod expires" solution nedds to change Apache server parameters. But my server is hosted by a provider so I don't have any access to their parameters. The timestamp solution works if page1.php is refreshed (so that the timestamp change). I assume my users will never (or almost) stay on this page and click several times on the PDF link but they will rather acess to page1.php everytime. So according to my needs, this solution works. Many thanks ! I feel it must be a more proper way though...

There are solutions to both problems you mention as well. If you cannot change the Apache config file you can probably use an .htaccess file, if not disallowed by your hosting provider. Move to another provider if they do. As for the URL, you could use Javascript to dynamically change the timestamp parameter of the URL. Then, even if users leave the page open, the URL will have changed and the newer version will be downloaded.

It is also possible to serve the PDF through a PHP script. That way you can send all the HTTP headers you like.

To Oliver's point, just serve the file with PHP. You can specify the file's name manually and control all the cache headers directly
